# Devise execute a method before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to restrict login to banned users. Each of my users has a `denied:integer, :default => 0` field that states if user is allowed to login or not.

If `denied == 1` then user is declined login.

However since I can't see the Devise controllers/models I don't know how to go about this, is there a before_login/before_auth filter I could use to apply my own method before login procedure is executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually really easy, just add the following to your user model.

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && !self.denied 
end
```

And use a boolean for your denied flag instead of an integer, it sets the column to a tinyint which is a bit neater and allows the boolean style !check. If you really need an int though, then just compare with `super && self.denied != 1`

[Rubydoc info](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable#label-active_for_authentication?)

Comment: If he leaves the integer denied value, this will always allow users to login.

Comment: This worked like a charm only downside is that it's displaying User not yet activated message when a banned user tries to login. I would need it to display another message.

Comment: @Zippie Assuming i had a boolean that would work, since i have an integer i simply changed to `self.denied == 0`